# Redirect URL to another URL in same site

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, url, redirect

I have just switched over to my new site (Magento based website) and the website has a gift registry function on it, as well as the old site. But now the old site links has been sent out for people to use it, and i require if someone uses the old url they will get to the new sites url

So I'm struggling to redirect an url from my old site to the new site

**Old site URL** `http://www.mydomain.com/GiftRegistry/tabid/349/ctl/ViewGiftRegistry/mid/1054/GiftRegistryID/76/Default.aspx?SkinSrc=/Portals/2/Skins/BinunsFinal/BinunsFinBrands`

**New site URL**    `http://www.mydomain.com/index.php/webtexgiftregistry/index/registry/id/EQPB91DMRBB1/key/d81fdd5ea5501b03c9d56ca1bfd917a2/`

Website is running on a windows server.

Comment: is your magento installation is on the root of `http://mydomain.com`? Why do your new site url contains `index.php`?

Answer (score 0):

Theres some more information that you might need to provide in order to get a full answer on this. You specify that this is a Magento site running on windows so are you running Apache/PHP/MySQL for windows or a variant there in WAMP for example, or are you using IIS to run the Web server.

If you are using Apache, you should be able to update the configuration of the server or use a .htaccess to setup some Redirect Rules in order to set up a 301 Redirect from the old URL to the new one.

From what I can see of your two sample URLS, you do not appear to have an obvious link between the two (ie no URL paramaters match) as a consequence you may be required to create a rule for each individual url to acheive this goal.

So for example in .htaccess or VirtualHost (if it is apache) you could enter:

```
Redirect /GiftRegistry/tabid/349/ctl/ViewGiftRegistry/mid/1054/GiftRegistryID/76/Default.aspx?SkinSrc=/Portals/2/Skins/BinunsFinal/BinunsFinBrands http://www.mydomain.com/index.php/webtexgiftregistry/index/registry/id/EQPB91DMRBB1/key/d81fdd5ea5501b03c9d56ca1bfd917a2/
```

IIS would be fundamentally the same process, but I have no experience on configuration of IIS redirects, the following may help you get that setup however. 
http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpredirect

Apache Reference: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

Comment: Hi Tank you for the response. I am running IIS, i have tried using the htaccess approach but it is not working. I will have a look at that iis link.